# How to get javascript object's value with key

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object like this code

```
var coinNameKR = {
  BTC: 'bitcoin',
  ETH: 'ethereum',
  DASH: 'dash',
}
```

And I want to get each value's with the key. So I search on stackoverflow and find this code

```
function getValueByKey(object, row) {
  return Object.values(object).find(x => object[x] === row.key);
}

console.log(getValueByKey(coinNameKR, row.key));
```

But It seems it only returns bitcoin only.

For example if

```
console.log(getValueByKey(coinNameKR, 'ETH'));
```

it should be ethereum, but still bitcoin. And I found get Key By Value but I can't not find get value by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return the value of the key in the object:

```js
var coinNameKR = {
  BTC: 'bitcoin',
  ETH: 'ethereum',
  DASH: 'dash',
}

function getValueByKey(object, row) {
  return object[row];
}

console.log(getValueByKey(coinNameKR, "ETH"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Solutions are really easy.. I think I should study more about javascript basic..

Comment: No worries @sangumee, always glad to help.

Comment: If all you are looking for is the value of a key why would you not just use coinNameKR.ETH or coinNameKR['ETH']?

Answer (score 1):

Is that is what you are looking for?

```js
var coinNameKR = {
  BTC: 'bitcoin',
  ETH: 'ethereum',
  DASH: 'dash',
}
for(let i in coinNameKR){
  console.log(`${i} has the value: ${coinNameKR[i]}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var coinNameKR = {
  BTC: 'bitcoin',
  ETH: 'ethereum',
  DASH: 'dash',
}

const dumpProps = obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => { console.log(`${key}'s value is ${obj[key]}`) });

dumpProps(coinNameKR);
```